# Generic method in C#

Tags: c#, android

I am trying to make a generic method in c# where I want to return a view.

I have the following function:

```
public static T findViewById<T>(View parent, int id)
        {
            return (T) parent.FindViewById(id);
        }
```

But i get an error saying :-

```
Cannot convert type Android.Views.View to T
```

any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Does adding a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) work? `findViewById<T>(View parent, int id) where T : Android.Views.View`

Comment: I think you need to constraint T, write `where T:View`

Comment: @RGraham Thanx for your comment. It worked. Please post an answer so that I can mark it accepted :)

Comment: That's OK, there are some other good more detailed answers down there which deserve a tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the code is too generic.  You haven't constrained T at all so any of these (and more) would be permissible:

```
var views = findViewById<int>(parent, id);
var views = findViewById<String>(parent, id);
var views = findViewById<Form>(parent, id);
```

And `views` would be an int or a string or a Form.  And you can't cast a `View` to any of these.

So basically, you are getting the compiler error because `Android.Views.View` cannot be cast to every possible T.

To make this work, you need to add a constraint to T to restrict T so that it will only be `Android.Views.View`

```
public static T findViewById<T>(View parent, int id) 
    where T : Android.Views.Views
{
    return (T) parent.FindViewById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can *restrict* generic parameter T being `View`:

```
public static T findViewById<T>(View parent, int id)
  where T: View
{
  return (T) parent.FindViewById(id);
}
```

this constraint make it easy to find errors like `findViewById<int>` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I take it `View` is the same as `Android.Views.View`. In this case, you can write:

```
public static T findViewById<T>(T parent, int id)
        {
            return parent.FindViewById(id);
        } where T : View
```